# Zoom in and out a video frame panel in Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere, zoom

In Adobe Premiere, I need sometimes to add some small custom masks. And I need to zoom in the video frame in this case. The only option I found is to manually drug a video panel border.

[image]

Are there special hotkeys for these actions (zoom in and zoom out video frame)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, well not for zooming but for maximizing and restoring the panel. These shortcuts may look different depending on the keyboard layout. On English layouts it's ` for the active frame, which is the frame with the thin blue border drawn around, and Shift+` for the frame under the cursor. The ` character is called acute or backtick.

If you use another keyboard layout and the ` does not work or you want to change the shortcuts, go to Edit menu -> Keyboard Shortcuts... Search for *Maximize* and you'll get "Maximize or Restore Active Frame" and "Maximize or Restore Frame Under Cursor".

Also, you can set zoom-in/-out shortcuts for the program monitor, but it zooms into the video and doesn't make the panel larger. Those shortcuts are not set by default.

Comment: Yes, zoom-in/-out shortcuts for the program monitor is what I was looking for. Thanks!